# selected value combo box binding not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have a window control in which I am loading a wpf user control.  The wpf user control contains a combo box which is bound to a property in the view model.  When I am debugging the code selected value property always has a value.  When the control is loaded for the first time I am getting the selected value, but when I reload the control the combo box gets cleared.  I tried everything; updating the source and other stuff, but it's still not working.  I even set the datacontext in code behind, but am still not getting the expected output.

This is the XAML code:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbType" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"       
 PreviewTextInput="cmbErrorType_PreviewTextInput" IsEditable="True"    
 MaxDropDownHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TypeList,Mode=OneWay}"    
 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}" DisplayMemberPath="Id"     
 SelectedValuePath="Id" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: Please show more code! Specifically the code where you reload the control.

Comment: And the code of the property the ComboBox is bound to.